# Horizontal Volume Bar in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm working on an custom video player. Got the rest of the elements in place, but cant for the life of me work out how to change the volume component from Horizontal to Vertical. I've tried standard stuff like rotation='90' but no joy on that.

Anyone have any ideas on what I should maybe modify or change to get it to a Vertical Slider rather than the current Horizontal state?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex 3:

```
<mx:HSlider/>
<mx:VSlider/>
```

In Flex 4:

```
<s:HSlider/>
<s:VSlider/>
```

Comment: He must have went another route or something, because this solution is *too* obvious.